# Writing a list containing point objects to a text file

Tags: java, list, io, java-io, outputstream

I'm trying to write a list that contains a list of points in to a text file.

Below is my point class

```
public class Point {

    private final double x;
    private final double y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }


    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("(" + x + "," + y + ")"); 
    }
}
```

A list of points is stored in a list

```
List<Point> pointList = new ArrayList();
pointList.add(new Point(100,200));
pointList.add(new Point(300,500));
pointList.add(new Point(400,200));
pointList.add(new Point(100,500));
pointList.add(new Point(400,200));
```

I would therefore like to save the points into a text file but I'm struggling to understand how this can be done because I'm new to java I/O.

Thanks for your help and time in advance.

EDIT:
I managed to write a method to save a a point to text file. However, I'm getting weird characters in the output

```
try {
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

                for(int i = 0; i < pointList.size(); i++){
                    String s = parseString( pointList.get(i));

                    out.writeObject(s);
                }
                out.close();
                fileOut.close();


            } catch (IOException i) {
                i.printStackTrace();
            }

private static String parseString(Point P){
        String point = String.valueOf(P.getX()) + "," + String.valueOf(P.getY()) ;
        System.out.println("String: " +point);
        return point;
    }
```

[image: output]

I would like the output to just have the doubles separated by a comma
Thanks

Comment: Didn't you search about `java IO` ? And your code has nothing to do with your question

Comment: You've not yet shown us your best good faith effort at solving this, nor have you told what problems you are having with your code attempt. Please do this soon as this will A) give us a much better understanding of what you're trying to do and prevent all this trouble extracting exact information from you, and B) give us a much better understanding of what you might be doing wrong, what you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: read a tutorial about IO. Second: some hints for your research. If there's no need for the file to be userreadable, i recommend you use ObjectOutput-/InputStream to read/write objects. For anything else you'll need to implement an own parsermethod `public static Point parsePoint(String s)` and simply write the results to a file using a filewriter.

Comment: I used a parsePoint to read in the points from a text file which had points in the form "100,200" on each line and then i used split(",") to split the string by a comma and then i added the return value from parsePoint into a list. But my problem now is writing the point list to a text in the same form.

Comment: create some method that returns the coordinates in the same form, and write them to the textfile in the same way. BufferedWriter might help.